# Alternatives to np.vectorize to apply functions in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Say I have a dataframe like this:

```
    ID Candy Wrapper Error
0  001  None       1  None
1  002     1    None  None
2  003     1       1   040
3  004  None       1   040
4  005     1       1  None
```

I want a new column like this:

```
    ID Candy Wrapper Error                 Reason to Follow Up
0  001  None       1  None    Matching candy not manufactured.
1  002     1    None  None  Matching wrapper not manufactured.
2  003     1       1   040                Factory malfunction.
3  004  None       1   040                Factory malfunction.
4  005     1       1  None                                None
```

The way I have always done this is with np.vectorize:

```python
def reason_to_follow_up(manufacture_candy, manufacture_wrapper, error):

    msg = []

    def candy_not_manufactured(manufacture_candy, manufacture_wrapper, error):
        if not manufacture_candy:
            if manufacture_wrapper:
                if not error:
                    msg.append("Matching candy not manufactured.")

    def wrapper_not_manufactured(manufacture_candy, manufacture_wrapper, error):
        if not manufacture_wrapper:
            if manufacture_candy:
                if not error:
                    msg.append("Matching wrapper not manufactured.")

    def specific_error(error):
        if error:
            if "40" in error:
                msg.append("Factory malfunction.")

    candy_not_manufactured(manufacture_candy, manufacture_wrapper, error)
    wrapper_not_manufactured(manufacture_candy, manufacture_wrapper, error)
    specific_error(error)

    if not msg:
        return None
    else:
        return ', '.join(msg)

df['Reason to Follow Up'] = np.vectorize(reason_to_follow_up)(df['Candy'],
                                                              df['Wrapper'],
                                                              df['Error'])
```

I like this for a few reasons:

1. I like to encapsulate all logic into one user defined function, and then run that function. I find that I can comment out my function verbosely, it's more modular, it sort of follows the formula builder in Excel which my teammates are familiar with, etc. Plus, I'm not familiar with many pandas built-in functions and find it hard to find them (eg. df. will bring up many autocomplete suggestions).
2. np.vectorize looks really clean.

Are there ways to apply my user defined function in a for loop, without even having to import numpy at the top?

Or maybe with pandas .apply or .map?

Full code sample:

```python
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'ID': ['001','002','003', '004', '005'],
            'Candy': [None, 1, 1, None, 1],
            'Wrapper': [1, None, 1, 1, 1],
            'Error': [None, None, "040", "040", None]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, dtype=str)

def reason_to_follow_up(manufacture_candy,manufacture_wrapper, error):

    msg = []

    def candy_not_manufactured(manufacture_candy,manufacture_wrapper, error):
        if not manufacture_candy:
            if manufacture_wrapper:
                if not error:
                    msg.append("Matching candy not manufactured.")

    def wrapper_not_manufactured(manufacture_candy,manufacture_wrapper, error):
        if not manufacture_wrapper:
            if manufacture_candy:
                if not error:
                    msg.append("Matching wrapper not manufactured.")

    def specific_error(error):
        if error:
            if "40" in error:
                msg.append("Factory malfunction.")

    candy_not_manufactured(manufacture_candy, manufacture_wrapper, error)
    wrapper_not_manufactured(manufacture_candy, manufacture_wrapper, error)
    specific_error(error)

    if not msg:
        return None
    else:
        return ', '.join(msg)

df['Reason to Follow Up'] = np.vectorize(reason_to_follow_up)(df['Candy'],
                                                              df['Wrapper'],
                                                              df['Error'])
```

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you can use pandas map; however, you can make it simpler using numpy select:  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html

```
 data = {'ID': ['001','002','003', '004', '005'],
        'Candy': [None, 1, 1, None, 1],
        'Wrapper': [1, None, 1, 1, 1],
        'Error': [None, None, "040", "040", None]}

 df = pd.DataFrame(data, dtype=str)



cond_candy=    df['Candy'].isnull() & df['Wrapper'].notnull() & 
               df['Error'].isnull()

cond_wrapper=  df['Candy'].notnull() & df['Wrapper'].isnull() & 
               df['Error'].isnull()

cond_error=    df['Error'].isin(['040'])

cond_else=     df['Candy'].notnull() & df['Wrapper'].notnull() & 
               df['Error'].isnull()

condlist =   [cond_candy, cond_wrapper, cond_error, cond_else]
choicelist = ["Matching candy not manufactured.",
              "Matching wrapper not manufactured.",
              "Factory malfunction.",
              None
              ]

df['reason'] = np.select(condlist,choicelist)

df


    ID      Candy   Wrapper     Error      reason
0   001     None        1       None    Matching candy not manufactured.
1   002     1         None      None    Matching wrapper not manufactured.
2   003     1           1       040     Factory malfunction.
3   004     None        1       040     Factory malfunction.
4   005     1           1       None    None
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I knew about list generators, but didn't realize I could actually zip up multiple columns and therefore use values from each of them:

```python
df['Reason to Follow Up'] = [reason_to_follow_up(manufacture_candy,manufacture_wrapper,error)
                                 for manufacture_candy, manufacture_wrapper, error
                                 in zip(df['Candy'], df['Wrapper'], df['Error'])]
```

This worked.

I timed this against np.vectorize and it's usually about double the speed.

However, I still think I'd use np.vectorize because it's still cleaner, and the bottleneck in my code is typically in the data visualization rather than operations piece.